# "push" changes on branch A to two other branches in same git repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

Instead of pushing to remote repo, is there a way to push changes for a certain branch to other branches in the same repo?

The rationale is that I want to avoid having to checkout the other branches and then run merge for each other branch

Normally, I would do

```
git commit -am "making changes to branch c"
git checkout a
git merge c
git checkout b
git merge c
```

I would rather not have to checkout the other branches, and just "push" the changes from c to the other branches.

something like:

```
git commit -am "making changes to branch c"
git push local a b   // not right at all
```

Hope it makes sense.

The only stuff I see online is how to push to a different branch if it's it a separate repo (a remote repo for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.  The trick to know is that a "remote" named `.` refers to your own local repository.<sup>1</sup>  Hence:

```
git push . HEAD:a HEAD:b
```

or:

```
git push . c:a c:b
```

(assuming `HEAD` names the same commit as `c`) does this.  Note that the adjustment to `a` and/or `b` must be a fast-forward, as would be required with any remote.  You can force the push but this has the same effect as with any remote (i.e., discarding some commits: pushing with `--force` is much like using `git reset`).

---

<sup>1</sup>This falls naturally out of the fact that any path, such as `git push /some/where/over/there`, is treated as a file URL, and `.` is a path, and `.` means "the current directory", and the push starts from the top of the repo, so the "other" repo is right here where ours is.